# Split column in dataframe R

Tags: r

I need to split a row of my data into columns. I am new to R it looks like its coming through as one big string but actually I want it as column headers.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try using :

```
data <- read.csv('filename.csv', skip = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df
# A tibble: 6 x 1
  x1                            
  <chr>                         
1 MeetingID, Date, JetBet, Track
2 49588,2020-11-03,6,Wingatui   
3 49588,2020-11-03,6,Wingatui   
4 49588,2020-11-03,6,Wingatui   
5 49588,2020-11-03,6,Wingatui   
6 49588,2020-11-03,6,Wingatui   
cnames <- df[1,,drop = T]
df <- df[2:nrow(df), ]
df %>% separate(col = x1, into = trimws(strsplit(cnames,split = ',')[[1]]), sep = ',')
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  MeetingID Date       JetBet Track   
  <chr>     <chr>      <chr>  <chr>   
1 49588     2020-11-03 6      Wingatui
2 49588     2020-11-03 6      Wingatui
3 49588     2020-11-03 6      Wingatui
4 49588     2020-11-03 6      Wingatui
5 49588     2020-11-03 6      Wingatui
```

Comment: I am now getting this Error in UseMethod("separate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'separate_' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: @Ivy44, so it says you can't use separate function on a character class, it works for tibbles/dataframes, are you entering the "into" argument values as given above?